# Change target framework to ".Net Standard"

Tags: .net-framework, visual-studio-2015

I have a project in Visual Studio 2015 update 3 which uses target framework 4.6.1.
I would like to change its target to ".Net Standard".
".Net standard" is not listed in the "Target framework" drop down list:
[Net standard is not listed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOnXs.jpg)

How can I do that ?
I'm using a Microsoft Dynamics 365 SDK version 10.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I do that?

Your inability to target .NET Standard is directly relate to the version of Visual Studio you are using.

> [image]

Source: [How to install .NET Standard 2.0](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2017/09/20/how-to-install-net-standard-2-0/)

> In order to build .NET Standard libraries in Visual Studio, make sure you have Visual Studio 2017 version 15.3 or later installed on Windows, or Visual Studio for Mac version 7.1 or later installed on macOS.

You will have to upgrade to the current version of **Visual Studio 2017** or **Visual Studio 2019** to acomplish your goal.

Source:

- [.NET Standard libraries and Visual Studio](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard#net-standard-libraries-and-visual-studio)
- [Installing a .NetStandard 2.0 Nuget package into a VS2015 Net 4.6.1 project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46788323/installing-a-netstandard-2-0-nuget-package-into-a-vs2015-net-4-6-1-project)
- [.NET Core Runtime and SDK download archive](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/download-archive.md#net-core-runtime-and-sdk-download-archive)
- [.NET Standard](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard)
- [Additions to the csproj format for .NET Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/csproj)
- [Cross-platform targeting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/library-guidance/cross-platform-targeting)
  Once you upgrade to Visual Studio 2017+ you would make the following modifications to your project's solution.

  netstandard2.0;net461

Comment: There are ways to reference .NET Standard libraries with Visual Studio 2015 but there isn't a way to target one of the versions of the .NET Standard and then compile your own project.  This was a feature introduced with Visual Studio 2017+